# Django - Using Cast to query if CharField values are gte when not all values are string representations of ints

Tags: django

I have a DataField model in django that I use to store values for various field types. It looks like this:

```
class DataField(models.Model):
    class FieldTypes(models.TextChoices):
        TEXT = 'Text', 'Text'
        QUANTITATIVE = 'Quantitative', 'Quantitative'
        SELECTION = 'Selection', 'Selection'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field_type = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=FieldTypes.choices)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

I want to be able to do a multi-query returning certain DataField types with certain values that are gte a given number, for example:

```
DataField.objects.filter((Q("value__gte"= 1000) & Q(name= 'credit'))| (Q("value"= "Smith") & Q(name='Last Name')))
```

The problem is that the value field is a CharField, so I can't do gte filters.  The field needs to be a CharField because I also store other word string values, like names.

I've tried using Cast to create a value_int field for the query, but since not all values for DataField.value can be converted to an int I get a syntax error:

```
queryset = DataField.objects.annotate(
    value_int=Cast('value', output_field=IntegerField()),).all()

django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Smith"
```

Is there a way I can add some logic to Cast so that if the value is not a valid integer it just goes to null?

Answer (score 0):

For numeric value type you have to use proper numeric field for comparison,

It is not recommended to use numeric field along with char field and filter then as supposed the field is of numeric

Because as suppose you have '2' saved as a charfield but actually it is numeric, the comparison let's suppose '2' > '10' will yield string comparison rather than numeric

So it is advised to save **name** as different field and the numeric value as another

Comment: That's why I am trying to use Cast to convert the values to integers.  DataFields can be created and used by users, I have to leave the field 'value' as a CharField for this to work

Comment: But you can only Cast numeric strings to Int, for ex- you can cast '2', '5.55' but not 'Name' it's like converting int("name")